# jQuery nextUntil higher level

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say there is a table like this (see the code snippet below):

```js
$("table tbody tr").click(function() {
  var category_level = $(this).data("grouping");
  var targetted_rows = $(this).nextUntil("[data-grouping=" + category_level + "]");
  targetted_rows.fadeToggle(300);
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

thead {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

thead th {
  width: 150px;
}

.heading {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.subtitle {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.item {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr data-grouping='category_0'>
      <td class="heading" colspan="3">Heading 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-grouping='category_1'>
      <td class="title" colspan="3">Title 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-grouping='category_2'>
      <td class="subtitle" colspan="3">Sub-title 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-grouping='item'>
      <td class="item">Item 1</td>
      <td class="item">Item 2</td>
      <td class="item">Item 3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-grouping='category_0'>
      <td class="heading" colspan="3">Heading 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-grouping='category_1'>
      <td class="title" colspan="3">Title 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-grouping='category_2'>
      <td class="subtitle" colspan="3">Sub-title 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-grouping='item'>
      <td class="item">Item 1</td>
      <td class="item">Item 2</td>
      <td class="item">Item 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The aim is clicking on a row with 
`data-grouping='category_3'` would toggle subset rows (e.g. rows with data-grouping='item'), but not any other rows. And, clicking on a row with data-grouping='category_2' should toggle visibility of rows with data-grouping of 'category_3' and 'item' and not any other row, and so on and so forth.

Is there a way to write this without resorting to a whole bunch of if statement?  Initially, I thought about nextUntil:

```
var category_level = $(this).data("grouping");
var targetted_rows = $(this).nextUntil("[data-grouping="+ category_level +"]");
targetted_rows.fadeToggle(300);
```

But, using this code, if you click on the last row with data-grouping = 'category_3', it would also toggle all rows with category_2, category_1, category_0 until it finds another row with category_3!  In other words, the corner case (the last element of a data-grouping) throws the code off its intended path.

Comment: You don't have any with `category_3`

Comment: The table is dynamic and might have category_3, category_4, ...